# pdfReactor generated documents don't have working links

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, hyperlink, pdf-reactor

I am trying to produce a pdf from HTML generated from `ReactServer.renderStaticMarkup`. I have noticed peculiar behavior around links.

As an example let's use a link to a photo.  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tICI.png'

I am able to use that link as the source of an `<img>` tag.  However, when I try to set it as the `src` of an `<a>` the link does not function.

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tICI.png">CLICK FOR SANITY</a>
```

putting that into the document seems like it should work, but alas it does not.

I am new to pdfReactor so there is likely something I am missing.  Does anyone have some thoughts on what might resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to set `addLinks: true` in your config when calling PDFreactor.

Source: https://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc/webservice/nodejs.html#Configuration-addLinks